# ¿Como hacer para mostrar las fechas entre un rango de fechas dadas con JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, jquery

buenas tardes.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente como puedo hacer para mostrar las fechas entre 2 fechas dadas por el usuario únicamente con JavaScript o Jquery, ya que la información la estoy obteniendo de un API yo únicamente me encargo del Frontend y no tengo acceso a la base de datos.

Es decir mostrar fechas entre el 2017-11-29 (29 de noviembre de 2017) y el 2017-12-05 (5 de diciembre de 2017)

debería de mostrarme lo siguiente

2017-11-29

2017-11-30

2017-12-01

2017-12-02

2017-12-03

2017-12-04

2017-12-05

De ante mano gracias por este espacio, espero mi pregunta pueda ser respondida.

```
if(date == since || date == until){
            var cReg = Object.keys(regis[cc][date]).length;
            console.log(cReg);
            if (regis[cc].hasOwnProperty(date)) {
              html += "<div class='panel panel-default'>"+
                      "<div class='panel-heading'><a href=#"+cc+"-"+i+" data-toggle='collapse'>"+date+
                        "</a><span class='badge'>"+cReg+"</span></div>";
                        html += "<div class='panel-body collapse' id="+cc+"-"+i+" >hours";
            //console.log();
              for (var hour in regis[cc][date]) {
                if (regis[cc][date].hasOwnProperty(hour)) {
                  html += "<div>"+ regis[cc][date][hour] +"</div>"
                }
              }
            }
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            i++;
       }else {
          console.log("la fecha no coincide");
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Sería recomendable ayudarte con "algo" que tengas y ver qué errores tienes.

Comment: tengo un if en el cual comparo las fechas que ingresa el usuario con las del archivo que me envia el API el lio es que me imprime esas fechas, ejemplo: si el usuario ingresa 22 de diciembre de 2017 hasta 28 de diciembre de 2017 solo me imprime los registros de esos dos dias y la idea es que  imprima esas y las que estan en ese rango, es decir tambien deberia mostrarme 23, 24, 25, 26 y 27. si me hago entender?

Comment: Agrega tu código.

Comment: Postea todo lo que has intentado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo podes hacer usando la libreria [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```js
var diasEntreFechas = function(desde, hasta) {
   var dia_actual = desde;
    var fechas = [];
   while (dia_actual.isSameOrBefore(hasta)) {
     fechas.push(dia_actual.format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
     dia_actual.add(1, 'days');
   }
   return fechas;
};

var desde = moment("2017-11-29");
var hasta = moment("2017-12-05");
var results = diasEntreFechas(desde, hasta);
console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: woowww muchas gracias, de echo estoy utilizando moment.js pero no sabia que con ella podia hacer este proceso

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 4):

Con **JavaScript** nativo es muy fácil de conseguir, solo es necesario conocer algunos métodos que provee para manipular fechas:

```js
var fechaInicio = new Date('2017-12-20');
var fechaFin    = new Date('2017-12-28');

while(fechaFin.getTime() >= fechaInicio.getTime()){
    fechaInicio.setDate(fechaInicio.getDate() + 1);

    console.log(fechaInicio.getFullYear() + '/' + (fechaInicio.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + fechaInicio.getDate());
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta del compañero Bender Paisa es válida pero tiene un pequeño error creo, el condicional debe ser:

```js
var fechaInicio = new Date('2017-12-20');
var fechaFin    = new Date('2017-12-28');

while(fechaFin.getTime() >= fechaInicio.getTime()){
    console.log(fechaInicio.getFullYear() + '/' + (fechaInicio.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +    fechaInicio.getDate());
    fechaInicio.setDate(fechaInicio.getDate() + 1);
}
```

De esta forma si se muestra el código tal como solicita el usuario. Saludos.